# Apex - Getting list of dates in month - CPU timeout

Tags: date, loop, cpulimit

I am getting a CPU timeout from my loop. I have checked the debug logs and my start and end dates have the correct dates in them. I have tried setting the condition to be dtoday.adddays(3) just as a test and got the same result. What am I not seeing?

```
List<Date> allDays = new list<Date>(); 
Date dToday = system.today();

date currentDay  = dToday.toStartOfMonth(); 
System.debug('CurrentDate = '+currentDay );     
date lastDay = dToday.toStartOfMonth().addMonths(1).addDays(-1);  
System.debug('LastDay = '+lastDay );    

while (currentDay < lastday) {
    allDays.add(currentDay);
    currentDay.addDays(1);
} 
system.debug('AllDays'+ allDays);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `addDays` method does not modify the value but instead returns the modified date. So you need:

```
currentDay = currentDay.addDays(1);
```

Your current code hits the CPU limit because `currentDay` never changes.

Comment: Ahhhh, yes now I see my mistake. Thanks! Haven't coded anything in months so rusty :(